# How to occupy the less memory at the time of xml parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am developing one application.In that i perform the xml parsing and get the 400 questions.For getting these questions i created one class with that question attributes.When the question tag is fired i created one object for that class  and saved that attributes information and when the didendelement fired for that class i added that class object into one array.Like this i create an object for every question.When i do like this it will take lot of memory and the process is also slow.If i run this one on background it will take same time.SO please tell me how to do this one with less memory.My parsing code is like

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict  
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"question"])
    {
        questions=[[Questions alloc]init];
        questions.content=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"content"];
        questions.id=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"id"];
        questions.answer=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"answers"];
        questions.type=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"type"];
        questions.markertext=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"marker_text"];
        questions.markertop=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"marker_top"];
        questions.markerleft=[attributeDict valueForKey:@"marker_left"];
    }
 }


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   [qshns addObject:questions];
}
```

Here qshns is the one array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to occupy less memory, that is just hit XML class just only one time and store it into an array or database in any singleton class. Then use it everywhere you want. Never hit XML class again and again it will occupy your large memory.

Comment: Please explain once again.I didn't understand.

Comment: just hit xml class just one time in appdelegate and store data in an array or in database. and use that array in any class.

Comment: But i Have different xml files for different subjects.based on previous page subject selection i need to parse the xml file for different questions.

Comment: then hit every xml once and store them into an array. if you have 100 XML then change your xml.

Comment: Same thing i am doing.But it will take lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your XML file in a Core Data datastore. You will then have super fast access with hardly any memory usage.

Comment: Every time i have different xml file.All these files are already stored in device memory.